# plsql- Oracle collections

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper, user-defined-types

How to fetch all the column from the table and store into the collection variable.(as single variable)

Hi guys,
please help me to write code among these questions in oracle plsql

Answer (score 1):

"How to fetch all the column from the table and store into the collection variable.(as single variable" - What if your table has millions/billions of rows? You want to flood your PGA memory!
You can use Bulk collect with a limit to fetch a limited number of rows and process them, when processing is complete you may store them somewhere and fetch the next set of rows.

By default, the optimizer puts Limit 100 after the `BULK COLLECT` clause. The PLSQL_OPTIMIZE_LEVEL needs to be set at level 2 or more.
Here is an example

```
DECLARE 

TYPE yourtable_nt IS TABLE OF yourtable%rowtype;
tab yourtable_nt;
CURSOR cur IS SELECT * FROM yourtable;

BEGIN
 
OPEN cur;

LOOP 
FETCH cur BULK COLLECT INTO tab LIMIT 100;  -- FOR EVERY FETCH DATA IS STORED IN tab FROM INDEX 1
     
      FOR i in 1..tab.COUNT LOOP 
      Null;
       -- PROCESS YOUR COLLECTION DATA
      END LOOP;

EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;

CLOSE cur;

EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF cur%ISOPEN THEN 
    CLOSE cur;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

You may need to find a sweet number for `BULK COLLECT LIMIT` for your table.
If your table has lots of rows try different numbers for `LIMIT`  otherwise the difference in execution time is insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

The question is too vague to offer a certain answer but this code is the solution to one interpretation of it: *"how to populate a PL/SQL collection which matches a table's projection?*"

```
declare
    --
    -- collection of records which match EMP table
    type emp_nt is table of emp%rowtype;
    --
    -- variable instance of that type
    emp_recs emp_nt;
begin
    -- use BULK COLLECT clause to populate the collection with records 
    select e.*
    bulk collect into emp_recs
    from emp e
    where e.deptno = 20;
end;
```